# I tried to build my game in unity-webGL and I got an error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I tried to build my game in webGL and i got this error

> "Could not find file
>   "C:\Users-----\OneDrive\Documents\Endless\Runner\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Native\build.bc"

The whole error is:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   "C:\Users\ethan\OneDrive\Documents\Endless
>   Runner\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Native\build.bc"
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode
>   mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share,
>   System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous,
>   System.IO.FileOptions options) (at
>   :0) System.IO.FileStream..ctor
>   (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess
>   access, System.IO.FileShare share) (at
>   :0) (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
>   System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) (at
>   :0) System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes
>   (System.String path) (at :0)
>   UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.LinkBuild
>   (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:470)
>   UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
>   (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:953)
>   UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
>   (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args,
>   UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Modules/DefaultBuildPostprocessor.cs:27)
>   UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess
>   (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget
>   target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName,
>   System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height,
>   UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry
>   usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:286)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

I'm rather new to unity and stackoverflow so don't be too hard on me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your project to another location. It could be a problem of file permissions with OneDrive.

Comment: Although that could be a problem I doubt it because I don't think OneDrive screws with permissions it will only help by syncing to your OneDrive

Comment: Do you use OneDrive?

Comment: No, but I have run things from the \OneDrive\Documents before. But not specifically Unity so don't take my word for it

Answer (score 0):

Normally most WebGL errors can be fixed by clearing the cache

This can be done by going to edit -> preferences and in the Preferences window go to GL cache tab and click clear cache.

Comment: This brought up a new error until I reopened unity now its back to this.